# Can DSolve is used to solve coupled differiential equations symbolically in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Iam trying to solve the Optical Bloch equations for two level using mathematica.

here is the code i wrote. i want to solve for Rho12 and see the variation of Imaginary part of Rho12 with respect to detuning [Capital Delta].

It is showing error that "they are transcendental equations"
Can some one help me....

```
\[CapitalOmega]21 = Conjugate[\[CapitalOmega]12];
n := \[Rho]11 + \[Rho]22 + \[Rho]12 + \[Rho]21 = 1;
Solution == DSolve[{
\[Rho]11'[t] == (\[CapitalGamma]2*\[Rho]22[t]) + 
  i/2 (\[CapitalOmega]21*\[Rho]12[t] - \[CapitalOmega]12*\[Rho]21[
       t]),
\[Rho]22'[t] == -\[CapitalGamma]2*\[Rho]22[t] + 
  i/2 (\[CapitalOmega]12*\[Rho]21[t] - \[CapitalOmega]21*\[Rho]12[
       t]),
\[Rho]12'[
  t] == (-(\[CapitalGamma]2/2) - i*\[CapitalDelta])*\[Rho]12[t] + 
  i/2*\[CapitalOmega]12*(\[Rho]11[t] - \[Rho]22[t]),
\[Rho]21'[t] == Conjugate[\[Rho]12'[t]] ,
\[Rho]22[0] == 0, \[Rho]11[0] == 1, \[Rho]12[0] == 
 0, \[Rho]21[0] == 0}, {\[Rho]11[t], \[Rho]22[t], \[Rho]12[
 t], \[Rho]21[t]}, t];
```

Comment: Your Conjugate appears to be what is confusing it. If you remove that and get rid of those assignments outside the DSolve then it solves. If you have to have that Conjugate you are going to have to find a way to give it more information. You didn't perhaps write i when you should have written I, did you? And it is Solution=DSolve, not Solution==DSolve. If you wrap a Simplify around your DSolve it will make the result less than half the size, but still very complicated with all those unknown variables used in your equations.

Comment: what does n do? it will throw an error if you ever use it.